# .NET - Find external applications main thread ID

Tags: .net, multithreading, external

I'm trying to find the handle of the **main** thread of an external application. The program I am trying to find the main thread of is multithreaded and it is important I always find the main thread. I know that at most there will be one copy of this program running. This is how I am doing it at the moment:

```
Process[] someProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("some");
IntPtr threadHandle = OpenThread(ThreadAccess.SUSPEND_RESUME, false, (uint)someProcesses[0].Threads[0].Id);
```

Most of the time, Threads[0] is the main thread but other times it is not. How can I make sure that the thread that I find is the main thread of the other application?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a wild guess, but via `Processes`, you can get a `ProcessThreadCollection` via the `Threads` property. Each thread has a `StartTime` (available as `Ticks` as well), so assuming the main thread is the first to start, you could pick the one with the lowest start time.

Otherwise if you can get the call stack for each thread, you could look for the application entry point. I couldn't find a managed call for that, but I'm sure you can get it through P/Invoke.

Comment: any idea how one might get a Dispatcher from the main thread?  I'd like to do this and then call Invoke to ensure that the calling application is displaying my GUI from the main thread.  From looking at the docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.aspx), I don't see a path to getting to the Dispatcher, like I do with normal `Thread`s via `FromThread`.

Comment: Given the information here (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/ed307fa4-5717-44e2-91ec-f219abf29dad), perhaps the thing to do, as ugly as it might be, is to find the main thread by StartTime, and then loop over all of the .NET threads and compare `main_thread.Id` to whatever `Thread` has the same value via `GetHashCode`.

Answer (score 0):

Talk about coming to the party late -- but if someone finds this in a Google search or something, what I do to ID my  main thread is set `Thread.CurrentThread.Name` to a value (like "Main") when my app starts up.